# How to design XML schema for book?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having problems with my xsd document not sure what I'm missing as it doesn't validate. Trying to make it such that the book id is an attribute of the book and the author initials and surname are encapsulated in an author element so that multiple author books are possible.

```
<ArrayOfBook>
   <Book id="cb001">
      <Author>
         <Initials>Charles</Initials>
         <Surname>Berlitz</Surname>
      </Author>
      <Title>The Bermuda Triangle</Title>
   </Book>
   <Book id="da001">
      <Author>
         <Initials>Douglas</Initials>
         <Surname>Adams</Surname>
      </Author>
      <Title>The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy</Title>
   </Book>
   <Book id="bor001">
      <Author>
         <Initials>Bill</Initials>
         <Surname>O'Reilly</Surname>
      </Author>
      <Author>
         <Initials>Dwight Jon</Initials>
         <Surname>Zimmerman</Surname>
      </Author>
      <Title>Lincoln's Last Days</Title>
   </Book>
</ArrayOfBook>
```

What am I missing in my XSD below ? Gives me an error when I try to validate  "The Content Of 'Author' Must Match (annotation?, (simpleType | ComplexType)?, (unique | Key | Keyref)*)). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Element."

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?> 
    <xs:schema id = "ArrayOfBook" xmlns:xs ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 

    <xs:simpleType name = "AuthorId"> 
      <xs:restriction base = "xs:string"> 
        <xs:pattern value ="[A-Za-z\s']+"/> 
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name = "ArrayOfBook">
      <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:sequence> 
          <xs:element name = "Book" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "unbounded"> 
            <xs:complexType> 
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "Author">
                  <xs:element name="AuthorInitials" type="AuthorId" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
                  <xs:element name="AuthorSurname" type="AuthorId" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
                  </xs:element>
                    <xs:attribute name="Id" type = "xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use following XSD to validate your XML.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<xs:schema id="ArrayOfBook" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="AuthorId">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z\s']+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="ArrayOfBook">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Author" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Initials" type="AuthorId" minOccurs="1"
                                            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                        <xs:element name="Surname" type="AuthorId" minOccurs="1"
                                            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```